# How can I concatenate these values and perform an md5 calculation

Tags: php, variables, md5, concatenation

I have some values:

```
$data1
$data2
$data3
```

I want to concatenate these variables and then perform an md5 calculation how is it done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
md5($data1 . $data2 . $data3);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
echo md5($data1.$data2.$data3);
```

Related:

- [PHP Manual on md5()](http://www.php.net/md5)
- [PHP Manual on Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: What to do if the order shouldn't affect the output ?

Comment: @Subin here's a related C# question, maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670063/getting-hash-of-a-list-of-strings-regardless-of-order

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by sorting the datas and then hash it.

Answer (score 1):

If your values are strings it's pretty easy

```
md5($data1 . $data2 . $data3);
```

If they are not string you need to first convert them.

Answer (score 1):

If your vars are no simple strings, but maybe objects or arrays you could go like this:

```
md5(serialize($data1 . $data2 . $data3));
```