# Why does Contains() return false but wrapping in a list and Intersect() returns true?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

**Problem:**

When I use `Contains()` against an `IEnumerable<T>` of classes that correctly implement `IEquatable` and override `GetHashCode` it returns false. If I wrap the match target in a list and perform an `Intersect()` then the match works correctly. I would prefer to use `Contains()`.

On `IEnumerable.Contains()` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880(v=vs.90).aspx):

> Elements are compared to the specified value by using the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms224763(v=vs.90).aspx) equality comparer

On `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` Property from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms224763(v=vs.90).aspx):

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable generic interface and if so returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

As far as I understand, implementing `IEquatable<T>` on my class should mean that the `Equals` method is used by the default comparer when trying to find a match. I want to use Equals because I want there to be only one way that two objects are the same, I do not want a strategy that the developers have to remember to put in.

What I find strange is that if I wrap the match target in a `List` and then perform an `Intersect` then the match is correctly found.

What am I missing? Do I have to create an equality comparer too, like the MSDN article? MSDN suggests that having `IEquatable` is enough and that *it* will wrap it for me.

**Example Console App**

NB: `GetHashCode()` from [Jon Skeet here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670063/getting-hash-of-a-list-of-strings-regardless-of-order/670068?noredirect=1#comment39633404_670068)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ContainsNotDoingWhatIThoughtItWould
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyEquatable : IEquatable<MyEquatable>
        {
            string[] tags;

            public MyEquatable(params string[] tags)
            {
                this.tags = tags;
            }

            public bool Equals(MyEquatable other)
            {
                if (other == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (this.tags.Count() != other.tags.Count())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                var commonTags = this.tags.Intersect(other.tags);
                return commonTags.Count() == this.tags.Count();
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                int hash = 17;
                foreach (string element in this.tags.OrderBy(x => x))
                {
                    hash = unchecked(hash * element.GetHashCode());
                }
                return hash;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Two objects for the search list
            var a = new MyEquatable("A");
            var ab = new MyEquatable("A", "B");

            IEnumerable<MyEquatable> myList = new MyEquatable[] 
            { 
                a, 
                ab 
            };

            // This is the MyEquatable that we want to find
            var target = new MyEquatable("A", "B");

            // Check that the equality and hashing works
            var isTrue1 = target.GetHashCode() == ab.GetHashCode();
            var isTrue2 = target.Equals(ab);


            var isFalse1 = target.GetHashCode() == a.GetHashCode();
            var isFalse2 = target.Equals(a);

            // Why is this false?
            var whyIsThisFalse = myList.Contains(target);

            // If that is false, why is this true?
            var wrappedChildTarget = new List<MyEquatable> { target };

            var thisIsTrue = myList.Intersect(wrappedChildTarget).Any();
        }
    }
}
```

[.NET 4.5 Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fye9i6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay - the problem is actually in the *array* implementation of `ICollection<T>.Contains`. You can see that simply like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ab = new MyEquatable("A", "B");
    var target = new MyEquatable("A", "B");

    var array = new[] { ab };
    Console.WriteLine(array.Contains(target)); // False

    var list = new List<MyEquatable> { ab };
    Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(target));  // True

    var sequence = array.Select(x => x);
    Console.WriteLine(sequence.Contains(target)); // True
}
```

`Enumerable.Contains` delegates to `ICollection<T>.Contains` if the source implements `ICollection<T>`, which is why you were getting the array behaviour rather than the `Enumerable.Contains` "long-hand" implementation in your code.

Now `ICollection<T>.Contains` *does* say it's up the implementation to pick which comparer to use:

> Implementations can vary in how they determine equality of objects; for example, `List<T>` uses `Comparer<T>.Default`, whereas `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` allows the user to specify the `IComparer<T>` implementation to use for comparing keys.

But:

- That documentation is broken already, as it should be talking about `EqualityComparer<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`, not `Comparer<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`
- The decision of arrays to use a comparer which is neither explicitly specified *nor* the default `EqualityComparer<T>` seems very unnatural to me.

The *solution* is to override `object.Equals(object)`:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    return Equals(other as MyEquatable);
}
```

It's generally pleasant to implement both `IEquatable<T>` *and* override `object.Equals(object)`, for consistency. So while your code *should* work already in my view

Comment: Imho this is a bug, either in the documentation or in the implementation, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you! Worked both in my toy problem and in my enterprise-level-application problem where it was originally discovered.