# Using LINQ GroupBy to group by reference objects instead of value objects

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, ienumerable, iequatable

I want to GroupBy multiple objects in a list of records and not simply multiple values.

I am having trouble getting grouping to work with reference type objects. I have a collection of objects that contain Room, Type, and DateTime. Room, Type, and DateTime all have properties associated with them. I've already added the IEquateable interface to the room and the type thinking that would be enough to with with group by.

```
var groups = collection
  .Where(g => g.Stage == InventoryStage.StageA)
  .GroupBy(g => new {g.BirthDate, g.Room, g.Type});
```

In order for this code to work i have to call our a specific property on these objects to group by. The problem with that is that i need the complex objects stored in the "Key" of the grouping so that i can access that groups specific information

```
var groups = collection
  .Where(g => g.Stage == InventoryStage.StageA)
  .GroupBy(g => new {
     Birthday = g.BirthDate, 
     RoomName = g.Room.Name, 
     TypeName = g.Type.Name
   });
```

I end up having to do ^ to get the grouping to work, however the groups lose the complicated object i wanted.

Comment: Your `Room` and `Type` should override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` or/and implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this task, you can override Equals() and GetHashCode() methods for your classes:

```
public class Room {
     public string Name;
     public string Foo;

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
         Room other = obj as Room;
         if (other == null) return false;
         return this.Name == other.Name && this.Foo == other.Foo;
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return (Name.GetHashCode() ^ Foo.GetHashCode()).GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812010/c-sharp-group-by-several-nested-properties-and-list-values) for more complicated example

Answer (score 2):

1. Your could override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in the main class that holds those properties instead of using the anonymous type in the `GroupBy`.
2. Another approach would be to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<YourMainType>`. You can use an instance of it for the overload of [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).
3. your `Room` and `Type` could override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` or/and implement `IEquatable<T>`. Implementing `IEquatable`/`IEquatable<>` isn't enough since `GroupBy` first uses `GetHashCode` to determine the hashcode  before it starts to compare objects with `Equals`, so that's the  initial filter.

Here's an example for the Room class:

```
public class Room:IEquatable<Room>
{
    public Room(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    /// <summary>Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.</summary>
    /// <returns>true if the current object is equal to the <paramref name="other" /> parameter; otherwise, false.</returns>
    /// <param name="other">An object to compare with this object.</param>
    public bool Equals(Room other)
    {
        return String.Equals(this.Name, other?.Name);
    }

    /// <summary>Determines whether the specified object is equal to the current object.</summary>
    /// <returns>true if the specified object  is equal to the current object; otherwise, false.</returns>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare with the current object. </param>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        Room other = obj as Room;
        return this.Equals(other);
    }

    /// <summary>Serves as the default hash function. </summary>
    /// <returns>A hash code for the current object.</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name?.GetHashCode() ?? Int32.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Now you can even use complex types as a property of an anonymous type.