# How to incorporate List<string> field in GroupBy()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of Diff objects
Diff looks like this

```cs
public class Diff
{
    ChangeAction Action // ChangeAction is an Enum
    string Type
    DateTime StartDateTime
    DateTime EndDateTime
    int rateId
    string rateDescription
    List<string> properties
    DayOfWeek day
    List<DaysOfWeek> DaysOfWeek
    DayOfWeek DayOfWeek

}
```

My LINQ query does not do what I think it will do. I am passing in `diff.properties` in the `GroupBy()`, which is a List and I want it to group when all string values in a list match

```cs
var results = diffs
    .GroupBy(diff => new { diff.properties, diff.Action, diff.Type, diff.StartDateTime, 
                           diff.EndDateTime, diff.rateId, diff.rateDescription}) 
    .Select(group => new Diff(
        group.Key.Action,
        group.Key.ScheduleType,
        group.Key.StartDateTime,
        group.Key.EndDateTime,
        group.Key.rateId,
        group.Key.rateDescription,
        group.Key.properties,
        group
            .Select(ts => ts.DayOfWeek)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(dow => dow)
            .ToList()))
    .ToList();
```

The only difference between `results` and `diffs` is that the singular `DayOfWeek` that was previously stored in `diffs` is now put into the plural `DaysOfWeek` field (but just 1 item in the list). Currently, same # of items in both `results` and `diffs`.

What I'd like to see in the results list are:

1. A shorter list that consolidates based on matching on all the grouping (including diff.properties list values)
2. This would also mean more than 1 item in the DaysOfWeek list.

**My question is:**

How can I change my LINQ query above to see what I want to see in `results`?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Are you misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: @Enigmativity I added my question at the bottom just now, thank you

Comment: @TravisJ - No, but the OP originally just gave a series of statements. They didn't explain where they were stuck, what attempts they made, or clearly asked us what they needed from us. A refresher on [ask] might be useful.

Comment: @Enigmativity - The statement "My LINQ query does not do what I think it will do" in coordination with the groupby statement seems pretty clear cut to me. A refresher on GetHashCode or Equals may be useful.

Comment: This problem would be a lot easier to solve if you were to override [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1) in `Diff`.

Comment: One of your `GroupBy` properties (`diff.properties`) is a `List<string>`. The default comparer for a `List<T>` is a reference comparison, so no two lists will ever match in this case. You'll need to write your own comparer for the `Diff` class, where you might use `.SequenceEqual` to determine equality between the `strings` in `properties`. Probably the same thing applies to the `Action` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grouping you are using with the anonymous type contains a `List<string>` which is causing you to get a 1-1 ungrouped set.

You need to either

- use a custom class for the grouping and overload `GetHashCode` and `Equals` as shown in this question: [Using LINQ GroupBy to group by reference objects instead of value objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761686/using-linq-groupby-to-group-by-reference-objects-instead-of-value-objects)

- OR -

- compose a string from the values, or a subset of them, being selected (`diff.properties, diff.Action, diff.Type, diff.startdatetime, diff.enddatetime, diff.rateId, diff.rateDescription`) that will serve as a unique key to group with

Comment: If I want to keep the anonymous grouping by using `new {...}`, would I then want to override Equals() and GetHashCode() that includes only those fields (because I only want to group by those fields)?

Answer (score 2):

A few of your `GroupBy` properties are reference types, and the default comparer for these types is a refernence comparison, so none of these will ever match. To overcome this, we can write our own `EqualityComparer` for the `Diff` class so we can compare them in our own way:

```
public class DiffEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Diff>
{
    public bool Equals(Diff first, Diff second)
    {
        if (first == null || second == null) return ReferenceEquals(first, second);

        if (first.Properties == null && second.Properties != null) return false;
        if (first.Properties != null && second.Properties == null) return false;
        if (first.Properties != null && second.Properties != null &&
            !first.Properties.OrderBy(p => p)
                .SequenceEqual(second.Properties.OrderBy(p => p)))
            return false;
        if (!first.Action.Equals(second.Action)) return false;
        if (!string.Equals(first.Type, second.Type)) return false;
        if (!first.Start.Equals(second.Start)) return false;
        if (!first.End.Equals(second.End)) return false;
        if (!first.RateId.Equals(second.RateId)) return false;
        if (!string.Equals(first.RateDescription, second.RateDescription)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Diff obj)
    {
        var hash = obj.Properties?.Aggregate(0,
            (accumulator, current) => accumulator * 17 + current.GetHashCode()) ?? 0;
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.Action.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.Type?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.Start.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.End.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.RateId.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.RateDescription?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        return hash;
    }
}
```

And finally we can use this custom comparer in our `GroupBy` method:

```
var results = diffs
    .GroupBy(diff => new DiffEqualityComparer())
    .Select( // rest of code omitted
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for this example! ChangeAction is an enum, and my answer above seems to work without implementing Equals() and GetHashCode() for ChangeAction. Is that because it's an enum?

Comment: Yep! I didn't see your answer, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Great! I will make a note that ChangeAction an enum in my post :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

Reading [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128996/groupby-on-complex-object-e-g-listt) and the comments + answers in this question helped me figure it out!

```cs
public class DiffComparer : IEqualityComparer<Diff>
    {
        public bool Equals(Diff x, Diff y)
        {
            return x.Action == y.Action &&
                x.Type == y.Type &&
                x.StartDateTime == y.StartDateTime &&
                x.EndDateTime == y.EndDateTime &&
                x.rateId== y.rateId &&
                x.rateDescription == y.rateDescription &&
                x.properties.SequenceEqual(y.properties);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Diff x)
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + x.Action.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + x.Type.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + x.StartDateTime .GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + x.EndDateTime.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + x.rateId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + x.rateDescription.GetHashCode();

            foreach (string prop in x.properties)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + prop.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }
```

And I made this edit to the LINQ:

```cs
var results = diffs
    .GroupBy(diff => diff, new DiffComparer()) 
    .Select(group => new Diff(
        group.Key.Action,
        group.Key.ScheduleType,
        group.Key.StartDateTime,
        group.Key.EndDateTime,
        group.Key.rateId,
        group.Key.rateDescription,
        group.Key.properties,
        group
            .Select(ts => ts.DayOfWeek)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(dow => dow)
            .ToList()))
    .ToList();
```