# Is there any c# function for making a set closed under union/intersection

Tags: c#, r, set, closures

I'm working on making a list of string arrays closed under union which means union of any two arrays must be there in the complete list.

To do so, I wrote my own code that iterates through the list of string arrays and add the new string arrays which are the union of two existing string arrays of a list only when the new array doesn't already exist in the list.

```
public static List<string[]> UnionClosed(List<string[]> kstructure)
{        
    for (int i = 1; i < kstructure.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < kstructure.Count; j++)
        {
            string[] kstate1 = kstructure[i];
            string[] kstate2 = kstructure[j];
            string[] unionStatesResult = kstate1.Union(kstate2).ToArray();
            int flag = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k < kstructure.Count; k++)
            {
                if (kstructure[k].Length == unionStatesResult.Length && kstructure[k].Intersect(unionStatesResult).Count()==kstructure[k].Length)
                {
                    flag = flag + 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (flag==0)
            {
                kstructure.Add(unionStatesResult);
            }
        }
    }

    return (kstructure);
}
```

The expected result is to get a list of string arrays that is closed under union.

For example,If I pass input: {{}, {"i1"}, {"i2"}, {"i3"}, {"i4"}, {"i1","i2"}, {"i1", "i3"}, {"i1", "i4"}, {"i1", "i5"},{"i2", "i3"}, {"i2","i4"}, {"i2", "i5"}, {"i1", "i2", "i3"}, {"i1", "i2", "i4"}, {"i1","i2", "i5"}, {"i1", "i3", "i4"}, {"i1", "i3", "i5"}, {"i2", "i3","i4"}, {"i2","i3","i5"},{"i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"}, {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i5"}, {"i1", "i3", "i4","i5"}, {"i1", "i2","i3", "i4", "i5"}}.

Then the expected output should be:{{}, {"i1"}, {"i2"}, {"i3"}, {"i4"},{"i1","i2"}, {"i1", "i3"}, {"i1", "i4"}, {"i1", "i5"},{"i2", "i3"}, {"i2","i4"}, {"i2", "i5"}, {"i3", "i4"}, {"i1", "i2", "i3"}, {"i1", "i2","i4"}, {"i1", "i2", "i5"}, {"i1", "i3", "i4"}, {"i1", "i3", "i5"},{"i1","i4", "i5"},{"i2", "i3", "i4"}, {"i2", "i3", "i5"}, {"i2", "i4", "i5"}, {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"}, {"i1","i2", "i3", "i5"}, {"i1", "i2", "i4", "i5"}, {"i1", "i3", "i4", "i5"},{"i2", "i3", "i4","i5"}, {"i1","i2","i3","i4","i5"}}.

I'm getting the output but the problem is it is very slow and it's not giving result for large number of string arrays. I wanted a List of size 500 to be closed under union, but this code hasn't provided me result.I want to know is there any c# functionality to do the same. In, R sets package provides the same functionality under binary_closure(). I want the same thing in  c#.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include sample inputs **and expected results based on those sample inputs**.

Comment: Would any of the packages in [NuGet, tagged statistics](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22statistics%22) help?

Comment: I tried with that union method. The problem is same, the code is slow for large data. I'm looking for a functionality that can make my list closed under union. In R, there is a package "sets" that provides the same functionality named binary_closure which is very fast. i want same functionality in c#. I searched a lot but no luck.

Comment: @Hans k esting , I couldn't find any functinality in NuGet Packages, could you please give me any hint about which package can provide the same functionality that I'm looking for.

Comment: You can almost certainly improve on this algorithm (there's lots of looping going on here), but it's hard to start without some example input/output to work with.

Comment: For example, did you intend to do this recursively - i.e. if your list starts with two string arrays A and B, so you add the union A|B, you then go on to consider A|A|B and B|A|B

Comment: @Mahakgarg please add the example input and output to your question.

Comment: @canton7 , yes I tried the approach that you discussed but that gave me out of memory exception error for large data.

Comment: Please add the [mcve] **to the question** not to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a bit more efficient by using HashSets for your set comparisons, rather than doing looping.

First, the input taken from one of your comments:

```
var input = new string[][]
{
    new string[0],
    new[] {"i1"},
    new[] {"i2"},
    new[] {"i3"},
    new[] {"i4"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2"},
    new[] {"i1", "i3"},
    new[] {"i1", "i4"},
    new[] {"i1", "i5"},
    new[] {"i2", "i3"},
    new[] {"i2", "i4"},
    new[] {"i2", "i5"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2", "i3"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2", "i4"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2", "i5"},
    new[] {"i1", "i3", "i4"},
    new[] {"i1", "i3", "i5"},
    new[] {"i2", "i3", "i4"},
    new[] {"i2", "i3", "i5"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i5"},
    new[] {"i1", "i3", "i4", "i5"},
    new[] {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5"},
};
```

We'll need a helper like this, which lets us compare to HashSets for equality:

```
public class HashSetEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>
{
    public static readonly HashSetEqualityComparer<T> Instance = new HashSetEqualityComparer<T>();

    public bool Equals(HashSet<T> x, HashSet<T> y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.SetEquals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(HashSet<T> obj)
    {
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/670068/1086121

        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));

        var comparer = obj.Comparer;
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (T element in obj)
        {
            hash = unchecked(hash + comparer.GetHashCode(element));
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Then, the code:

```
var output = new HashSet<HashSet<string>>(HashSetEqualityComparer<string>.Instance);

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    // We need to make sure that every input item is in the output
    output.Add(new HashSet<string>(input[i]));

    for (int j = i + 1; j < input.Length; j++)
    {
        // It annoys me that we have to create a HashSet<string>(input[i]))twice
        var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(input[i]);
        hashSet.UnionWith(input[j]);
        output.Add(hashSet);
    }
}
```

For each combination of first and second string, we create a new HashSet. We then try and add that `HashSet<string>` to our HashSet output, which is a `HashSet<HashSet<string>>`. Our custom `IEqualityComparer` will make sure it's only added if it doesn't already exist.

We also keep the input and output collection separate, so we don't start processing the output as if it was input (which adds a lot of unnecessary work).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: @Mahakgarg If you find an answer useful, please consider upvoting it. If an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Your code is definitely faster than mine but still this approach is slow. I am not getting output if there are large number of elements in the set. Is there any other approach possible?

Comment: In R, "sets" package function binary_closure is doing same thing via a c code, When I tried to do the same by constructing c dll and then calling it in  c# code, then I got so many errors in reading the source file. Please suggest if you know anything to fix it.